# How to recursively call a function in python to drop every element in a list to the bottom?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion

For example, if my original nested list is :

```
[[' ', 'Y', ' ', 'X'], 
 ['S', ' ', 'V', ' '],
 ['T', 'X', 'Y', 'S'], 
 ['X', ' ', 'X', 'Y']]
```

I would like the result to be:

```
[[' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], 
 ['S', ' ', 'V', 'X'], 
 ['T', 'Y', 'Y', 'S'], 
 ['X', 'X', 'X', 'Y']]
```

So basically drop all the letters to the bottom without getting rid of any of the spaces and maintaining the structure of the list.

Here is what I have so far.
My result gives me this which is incorrect.

```
[[' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 ['S', 'Y', 'V', 'X'],
 ['T', ' ', 'Y', 'S'],
 ['X', 'X', 'X', 'Y']]
```

```
def find_letters(m,constant):

    try:

        for i in range(len(m[constant])):
            if m[constant][i] == ' ':

                if m[constant - 1][i] != ' ':
                    m[constant][i] = m[constant - 1][i]
                    m[constant - 1][i] = ' '

        find_letters(m,constant - 1)   

    except IndexError:

        pass  



l = [[' ', 'Y', ' ', 'X'],
     ['S', ' ', 'V', ' '],
     ['T', 'X', 'Y', 'S'],
     ['X', ' ', 'X', 'Y']]
constant = -1   

(find_letters(l,constant))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this.

You need to push all `' '`'s upwards in each column and rest all other characters downwards maintaining order. You can use `sorted()` here.

```
a=[[' ', 'Y', ' ', 'X'],
   ['S', ' ', 'V', ' '],
   ['T', 'X', 'Y', 'S'],
   ['X', ' ', 'X', 'Y']]

out=list(zip(*[sorted(lst,key=lambda x: x==' ',reverse=True) for lst in zip(*a)]))
''' [(' ', ' ', ' ', ' '),
   ('S', ' ', 'V', 'X'),
   ('T', 'Y', 'Y', 'S'),
   ('X', 'X', 'X', 'Y')]'''
```

Answer (score 0):

to operate more simple over the columns you could use [np.arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) with [np.apply_along_axis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) function:

```
m = np.array([[' ', 'Y', ' ', 'X'], 
 ['S', ' ', 'V', ' '],
 ['T', 'X', 'Y', 'S'], 
 ['X', ' ', 'X', 'Y']])

np.apply_along_axis(lambda c: [' '] *  list(c).count(' ') + [e for e in c if e != ' '],0 ,m)
```

output:

```
array([[' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
       ['S', ' ', 'V', 'X'],
       ['T', 'Y', 'Y', 'S'],
       ['X', 'X', 'X', 'Y']], dtype='<U1')
```

if you want python list of lists you can use [ndarray.tolist()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) function:

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda c: [' '] *  list(c).count(' ') + [e for e in c if e != ' '],0 ,m).tolist()
```

output:

```
[[' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 ['S', ' ', 'V', 'X'],
 ['T', 'Y', 'Y', 'S'],
 ['X', 'X', 'X', 'Y']]
```